# How to copy a record from Excel and paste into SSMS V 17 to update existing record

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms

Folks,

I am a novice, really a business user (not techie), in SSMS v 17. I used to update a MS Sql Server database in Azure using Excel add-in (Devart), but then Active Directory Multifactor Authentication was introduced at the organization and I cannot use Devart any longer. I am forced to use SSMS v 17.5 to make updates to the database through that grid.

I found a few old (circa 2008) solutions for creating new records using Copy Paste from Excel. Similarly, is there a way to "update" an existing record in the database by copying a row from Excel and pasting into that "grid"? I have some 60+ and 70+ year olds in the team, and would really like a simple solution that could cater to all ages. Right now, we scroll right and left, furiously, inside the grid trying to ensure that we are updating the correct row of record.

I sincerely appreciate your guidance in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this, though I do not recommend is:
1) Right click the table you want to edit, select edit top 200 rows. 
2) Right click the screen that pops up, go to Pane -> SQL
3) Change this to show the records you want to edit and column in the order you want and it should work.

Big problem here and why  I wouldn't suggest this, is if anything is wrong you could really mess stuff up, also it will lock the rows you are looking at which could affect other things. A better "work around" would be to create an excel function and use a template. Example : ="Update "&B1&" Set "&C1&" = '"&D1&"' where ID = "&A1 ... Essecially letting Excel write the dynamic sql. In this case B1 would be the table to update, Cell C1 would be the column to update, D1 would be the new value and A1 would be the unique identifier.  I do this often when someone sends me a list of 1000 items and I need to put them in a temp table or something.

Comment: Thank you for point out towards the "Pane" option. Instead of using SQL from there, I used Criteria. As I pointed out in my original post, I have baby-boomers on my team. That simplicity was welcomed.